# unable to set formula in SXSSFSheet using apache poi

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi, formula

I writing more than 100000 records in SXSSFSheet using apache poi - 3.13-beta1

When I am trying set the summation formula, it is returning zero

here is my code is

```
    SXSSFRow subtotalRow = (SXSSFRow) excelSheet.createRow(5);
    String strFormula= "SUM(I2:I11)";
    SXSSFCell cell = (SXSSFCell) subtotalRow.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
    cell.setCellFormula(strFormula);
```

please help. thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of the first line, too many open braces: `createRow((5);`

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a copy and paste error.

Comment: yes.its just copy paste error. just ignore it. I created a formula cell in 5th row. But the results shows 0 only

Comment: I can't see any code performing an evaluation of the formula cell. Did you [forget to follow the instructions on the Apache POI website to do that](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)?

Comment: I am not reading the cell value. Actually I need to set the formula for the cell value. Also I am using latest version of apache poi